# Is there any way to disable the replay cache when authenticate with SSPI?

Tags: sspi

I uses SSPI Kerberos do user authentication on Windows. While the AcceptSecurityContext() always fail when it receives a same token from client. It seems caused by replay cache. Is there any way to disable it on Windows with C?

Comment: be more specific problem : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have ever encounter same issue with GSSAPI, and resolved it by setting environment variable KRB5RCACHETYPE to "none". Is there similar method for SSPI?